# VkDescriptorBufferInfo range is x which is greater than this device's maxStorageBufferRange

Tags: vulkan

I'm using vulkan api for GPGPU computing for compatibility reasons.
I want to use vulkan compute shader for image processing task. I have 8 bit color rbg image
which I want to transfer to `VkBuffer`. As glsl doesn't support 8 bit data so I want to type caste to C 32 bit int and copied to `VkBuffer` . Now the problem is Buffer storage becomes huge for it. I get validation error something like this

```
 vkUpdateDescriptorSets() pDescriptorWrites[0] failed write update validation for VkDescriptorSet 0x7c45730000000006[] with error: Write update to VkDescriptorSet 0x7c45730000000006[] allocated with VkDescriptorSetLayout 0xf018750000000004[] binding #1 failed with error message: Attempted write update to buffer descriptor failed due to: For buffer VkBuffer 0x683e70000000002[] VkDescriptorBufferInfo range is 432000000 which is greater than this device's maxStorageBufferRange (134217728). The Vulkan spec states: If descriptorType is VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_BUFFER or VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_BUFFER_DYNAMIC, the range member of each element of pBufferInfo, or the effective range if range is VK_WHOLE_SIZE, must be less than or equal to VkPhysicalDeviceLimits::maxStorageBufferRange
```

In opencl I don't get this type of problem for data even more than this.

Here is my `VkBufferCreateInfo`

```
VkBufferCreateInfo bufferCreateInfo = {};
bufferCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
bufferCreateInfo.size = bufferSize;
bufferCreateInfo.usage = VK_BUFFER_USAGE_STORAGE_BUFFER_BIT;
bufferCreateInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
```

What can I do to handle larger data (300-400MB)?

Comment: "*As glsl doesn't support 8 bit data*" Yes, it does, assuming your implementation allows that image format.

Comment: If your implementation only supports 128MB SSBOs, that's probably because it doesn't have very much storage. So a 400+MB SSBO isn't going to work because you don't have 400+MB to play with. Also, is this MoltenVK or a mobile chipset or something, because most hardware has more than 128MBs to play with.

Comment: @NicolBolas How can I process 8 bit data in glsl

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? Process it through what interface?

Comment: @NicolBolas I want to pass uint8 array to glsl and perform operation on it like convolution

Comment: Buffer is just bytes. If you have just uints then unpack the uints in the shader to four bytes. Otherwise there is `storageBuffer8BitAccess` and `uint8_t`.

Comment: In other words, you use bitshifts and bitwise (or something like (bitfieldExtract)[https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/bitfieldExtract.xhtml]) to get bytes from 32bit ints. You may also want to use (unpackSnorm)[https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/unpackUnorm.xhtml] - it automatically converts your 32bit ints to float vectors, as if the bytes were normalised ints. If you want actual 8bit values though, you will need extensions.

Comment: Also, why don't you use image directly with image load/store?